# TEXT column: Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of lower function

Tags: java, sql, jpql

I currently have a repo method which is acting as a filter with pagination:

Repo:

```
 @Query("SELECT e FROM DeTest e  " +
            "WHERE e.deactivationTime = '9999-12-31 00:00:00.000' " +
            "AND (:name is null OR LOWER (e.name) LIKE LOWER ('%' + :name+ '%')) " +
            "AND (:description is null OR LOWER (e.description) LIKE LOWER ('%' + :description + '%')) " +
            "AND (:theProblem is null OR LOWER (e.theProblem ) LIKE LOWER ('%' + :theProblem + '%')) "
    )
```

So as shown here, I have it so when you enter a value it will change it ensuring that both uppercase values and lowercase values are displayed. However, when adding LOWER to the 'theProblem' column, it produces the error in the title:

```
Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of lower function
```

My datatype for that particular column is text, and therefore, I think the culprit of the issue. However, due to the db layout I need it to be a text. Therefore, is there anyway I could convert/cast it in the repo method for when it's called?

Column:

```
@Column(name = "the_problem", columnDefinition = "TEXT") // text rather than varchar
private String theProblem;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)